# Probability normal distribution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability, normal-distribution

I have a normal distribution with given mean 10 and variance 40. Now I want to know the probability that a number from this distribution is smaller than 0. Is it correct to use the following one-liner in MATLAB (in order to get the exact probability)?

```
normcdf(0,10,sqrt(40))
```

Comment: See for yourself, Monte Carlo style: `mean(10+randn(1,1e7)*sqrt(40)<0)`

Comment: @downvoters: I don't see a reason to downvote this. It may not be the deepest question ever, but as far as I can see it fulfills all the criteria for a question on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Alternatively, you could write

```
normcdf(-10 / sqrt(40))
```

which gives the same result of 0.0569231490033291.

To double-check whether Matlab's implementation is correct, you can also look up the CDF at `-10 / sqrt(40)` = -1.58113883008419 in a normal distribution table. [Wikipedia's table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Cumulative_table) gives a CDF value of 0.9429 at z = 1.58; its complement is 0.0571 – a match given the limited precision.

Comment: +1 Or, if you don't have the Stats toolbox: `erfc(10/sqrt(40) / sqrt(2)) / 2`